# How to Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{4^x-3^x}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to find this limit without using L'Hospital rule

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{4^x-3^x}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly do you need help? Any ideas at all? Please use the math notation environment that is provided. It is difficult to see, what limit you actually want to calculate.

Comment: Do you mean: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1-x}{3}-1}{4^x-3^x}$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-x)^\frac{1}{3}-1}{4^x-3^x}$, I think.

Comment: the solution is given by $$\left( -6\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +3\,\ln  \left( 3 \right)  \right) ^
{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use, binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{1/3}$ & Taylor's series expansion of $4^x$ & $3^x$ as follows   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{4^x-3^x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1!}(-x)+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}-1\right)}{2!}(-x)^2+\ldots\right)-1}{\left(1+x\ln 4+\frac{x^2}{2!}(\ln 4)^2+\ldots\right)-\left(1+x\ln 3+\frac{x^2}{2!}(\ln 3)^2+\ldots\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1!}(-x)+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}-1\right)}{2!}(-x)^2+\ldots}{\left(x\ln 4+\frac{x^2}{2!}(\ln 4)^2+\ldots\right)-\left(x\ln 3+\frac{x^2}{2!}(\ln 3)^2+\ldots\right)}$$
Dividing numerator & denominator by $x$,
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}-1\right)}{2!}(x)+\ldots}{\left(\ln 4+\frac{x}{2!}(\ln 4)^2+\ldots\right)-\left(\ln 3+\frac{x}{2!}(\ln 3)^2+\ldots\right)}$$

$$=\frac{-\frac{1}{3}+0}{\left(\ln 4+0\right)-\left(\ln 3+0\right)}$$
$$=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{3\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{4^x-3^x}=
\lim_{x\to0}
\frac
{\dfrac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{x}}
{\dfrac{4^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}}
$$
Compute each of the three parts and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

$Step\,1.$  $(1+x)^a = 1+ax + O(x^2)$ for all a and all $x$ with $|x|<1$

$Step\,2.$  $ 4^x - 3^x= 4^x\left(1-\left(\frac34\right)^x\right)$

$Step\,3.$ $(3/4)^x = \exp(x \ln(3/4)) = 1+ x \ln(3/4)+ \frac{x^2}2 \ln^2(3/4)+ O(x^3)$.

$Step\,4.$ The limit $L= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\frac13x + O(x^2)-1)}{4^x ( -x \ln(3/4)+O(x^2))}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\frac13 x}{ -x\ln3/4 }=-\frac1{3\ln4/3}.$